# Arithmetic overflow error in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

So just to give you an example of how our procedure would eventually work with data and come up with this error, here's some SQL:

```
DECLARE @daysInPeriod  INT
DECLARE @dcFraction    DECIMAL(38,38)
DECLARE @YEAR_360         DECIMAL
SET @YEAR_360 = 360.0000000000
SET @daysInPeriod = DATEDIFF(dd, '12/24/1970', '6/29/07')
SET @dcFraction = @daysInPeriod/@YEAR_360
```

If you run this in SQL Server 2008 R2, you'll see that you receive an `'Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.'` error.

The `decimal` that I am setting the value to is max'd out in terms of places it can hold, which I believe is 38. I don't know what else I can do to get this value. Shouldn't you be able to divide an `integer` with a `decimal` in SQL and get something out of it, especially if the `decimal` is max'd out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your example, the value of `@daysInPeriod/@YEAR_360` is `37.0444444444444444444`. So you can't assign that value to a parameter of data type `DECIMAL(38,38)`, since you are leaving no room the int part. A `DECIMAL(38,38)` means that you can store 38 digits, and 38 of them are on the decimal part, so any value greater than 0.999999999999 will throw an error.

Comment: Oh wow I probably should of looked up the decimal declaration first. This was in the code already so I incorrectly assumed it was written right the first time. Thanks!

Comment: @slandau Yes you probably should but these things happen to all of us when working with other peoples code in an unfamiliar language, we assume the other guy knew what he was doing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your declaration of `@dcFraction` as `DECIMAL(38,38)`. You're saying you want all 38 digits to the right of the decimal point, with no room for the integer portion to the left.

Answer (score 1):

If you give your decimal a smaller scale, it is going to work:

```
DECLARE @daysInPeriod  INT
DECLARE @dcFraction    DECIMAL(38,12)
DECLARE @YEAR_360         DECIMAL
SET @YEAR_360 = 360.0000000000
SET @daysInPeriod = DATEDIFF(dd, '12/24/1970', '6/29/07')
SET @dcFraction = @daysInPeriod/@YEAR_360
select @dcFraction
```

This returns `37.044444444444`